# How do I add NavigationDrawer from an activity template to other activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been playing around with the Drawer Menu activity template from Android Studio since I haven't used a drawer menu before. Here's the layout file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Includes a Toolbar and FloatingActionButton. Generated by Android Studio-->
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer_menu" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_side_menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Android Studio also generated an Activity class as part of the template. My app has a main activity as well that uses a LinearLayout. I want to use Fragments to add the drawer menu to the main activity (and other activities), but I'm unsure how to do this. Do I need to create a new subclass of fragment and adapt DrawerMenuActivity's callback methods for the fragment class? Then do I add a fragment tag to activity_main.xml?

Answer (score -1):

This will likely be something you need to wrap your head around...

Ideally, you want to swap fragments in a container located in the the xml for the MainActivity by using fragment transaction and calling replace with the fragment to be placed in the container. This will allow you to re-use the container and offer the drawer to the entire app.

Otherwise, you would need to include the drawer in every activity which creates a lot of extra code or not offer the drawer which depending on the activity you may be able to get away with that.

So, the drawer works with fragments being swapped in via the transaction and not so well for additional activities. Its something you need to design around.

Please, create a new project with a generated drawer for an Activity and proceed from there. Also read the android developer tutorial for fragments part on communication to see how the drawer fragment and activity communicate.

There's actually quite a bit involved for the drawer but you should be able to get a good grasp in a day or two.

Comment: I think I see what to do know. I was thinking that I could switch entire activities using the NavigationDrawer, but now I figured out how to properly swap fragments using a drawer menu.